# Opportunity Creation Stage 1 Validation Rule

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule

I'd like to have a Validation Rule that requires Opportunities to be created, via conversion or organic creation, in Stage 1. How can I do this?

`NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName,"1 - Plan")) && $User.Bypass_Workflows__c = false && NOT(ISPICKVAL(Order_Type__c, "Decommission"))`

Comment: Hi Tamim -- you should check out [ask] as the community tends to like folks who demonstrate they have tried something first. Otherwise, try the salesforce success forum

Comment: @cropredy, I am very familiar with how to write the `NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName,"1 - Plan")) && $User.Bypass_Workflows__c = false && NOT(ISPICKVAL(Order_Type__c, "Decommission"))`, but didn't because this group will likely be bored with that extraneous information, since the only hiccup here is I don't know how to add the "upon Opp. creation" criteria. Thank you for the advice, and no help, nonetheless.

Comment: ah, Tamin, the community is not at all bored with detail!  Sometimes it is hard to sort out folks who just want the community to do their work for them as opposed to someone who is stuck on some point and has progress to show.  I'm sure if you [edit] your question with the snippet you've written, the community will be happy to help

Comment: @cropredy, all set!

Comment: did you try `ISNEW()` as a condition?

Comment: So, how about, `ISNEW() && NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName,"1 - Plan")) && $User.Bypass_Workflows__c = false && NOT(ISPICKVAL(Order_Type__c, "Decommission"))`?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you should need to add is `&& ISNEW()`

Comment: If you add a complete example of what you think the formula should be, your answer is less likely to get flagged for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured it out, and pasted-below the solution. We have a few different Order Types on Opportunities, so I've scoped in the Rule for those pertinent to it. Thank you to all that assisted, especially @cropredy.

`ISNEW() && NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName,"1 - Plan")) && $User.Bypass_Workflows__c = false && OR(ISPICKVAL(Order_Type__c, "New"), ISPICKVAL(Order_Type__c, "AddOn"))`